# Problem using comma in from field in headers of php mail

Tags: php, email, mailer

How can i put commas in the 'From:' field of the mail headers??

For example with "From:Javier, My Site" when i read the email sended with any mail client like outlook, in the From only appears **Javier@myinternalserverurl.com**.

It cuts the from field by the comma... All the things that i found about 'From' field in php mails says that if you put commas automatically is treated like a list of mails.. any suggestion?

Thanks in adevice!

Comment: i have tried without succes.. the solution below works perfect, thanks anyway

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`"From: \"Javier, My Site\" <email@domain.com>"` should work

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work properly on Windows.